# How can I handle published message from my input queue as well as publish it to remote endpoint?

Tags: rebus

I currently configured rebus to direct all messages in *MyMessages* assembly to the process managers input queue. Suppose in MyMessage assembly I have a message called **SomethingHappened** which will be used to trigger other actions in process managers (e.g. **DoSomethingElse**). However, I also want to subscribe **SomethingHappened** locally (in the same queue) to update the database. So the workflow will look like:

1. User trigger the action **DoSomething** in the UI
2. The handler of **DoSomething** updates the object state and publish events **SomethingHappened** internally (in memory collection of uncommitted events)
3. **SomethingHappened** events get published by rebus to the queue by go through all uncomitted events in the object
4. Handle **SomethingHappened** locally to update database
5. Handle **SomethingHappened** remotely by saga to trigger **SomethingElseHappened**

Is this possible to be configured in rebus?

The rebus configuration I currently have:

```
<rebus inputQueue="input" errorQueue="error" workers="1" maxRetries="5">
    <endpoints>
        <add messages="MyMessages" endpoint="processManagers.input"/>
    </endpoints>
</rebus>
```

Thank You

Yin

Comment: My mistake. I should change the endpoint to configuration to input. And then never, never subscribe to commands. : )

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I should change the endpoint to configuration to input. And then never, never subscribe to commands. :)

```
<rebus inputQueue="input" errorQueue="error" workers="1" maxRetries="5">
    <endpoints>
       <add messages="MyMessages" endpoint="input"/>
    </endpoints>
</rebus>
```